# Django adding an attribute to a model formset

Tags: django, django-forms

How do I go about adding a new class attribute for each for my fields in my formset? I was thinking it would be along these lines of code but the attribute fields does not exist in a formset object.

```
 55 # create the formset
 56 ItemUserDetailsFormset = modelformset_factory(CartItemUserDetails,
 57             exclude=['cart', 'cart_item'], formset=BaseItemUserDetailsFormset)

 37 class BaseItemUserDetailsFormset(BaseModelFormSet):
 38     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
 39         super(BaseItemUserDetailsFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
 40         self.fields['first_name'].widgets = forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":"required"})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to set the `fields` attribute on the *formset*. You need to set it on the *form* class, not the *formset* class.

So, you want something like...

```
class ItemUserDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CartItemUserDetails

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ItemUserDetailsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['first_name'].widget = forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'required' })
        # [...]

ItemUserDetailsFormset = modelformset_factory(CartItemUserDetails, 
    form=ItemUserDetailsForm, 
    exclude=['cart', 'cart_item'],
)
```

Sadly, I scanned the docs and didn't see documentation of the `form` keyword argument in the Django docs, but it's clearly presented if you look at [the `modelform_factory` function itself](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/forms/models.py) (see line 371).

Also, if the only thing that you're changing is the widget property, and if you're using Django >= 1.2 (which you should be), there's a [slightly simpler syntax](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-field-types-or-widgets) on the form itself:

```
class ItemUserDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CartItemUserDetails
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={ 'class': 'required' }),
            # [...]
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! One question though, seeing the code made me wonder I was about to pass in a formset variable to `modelformset_factory` in the first place?

Comment: You pass the `form` kwarg to `modelformset_factory`.